# Too Many Pages in Wordpress? 2013

Tags: pages, performance

I've read a few threads both here and elsewhere about Wordpress having performance issues once a certain amount of pages have been published. But, most of these threads are at least a couple years old, and it seems like an issue that Wordpress would try to fix.

So - my question - does anyone know if this is still an issue?  If, so are there any work arounds that would keep performance issues from occurring?  I'm thinking of building a site using mostly static pages, and the site could grow into the 5,000 - 10,000 page range.

Thanks!

Comment: I've got many times that in posts and custom post types and the site works fine. Since there is no real difference behind the scenes between post, CPTs, and pages I'd expect no problems. But the details of your setup could make a big difference and without the ability to test we are all speculating. I don't think this is answerable as it stands.

Comment: The only difference between a few posts and lots of posts is the number of entries in the database. You would need an EXTREMELY large # of posts before it would start affecting load time, methinks. Of all the things that might slow load time, post count is past the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 3):

Many pages were a problem when your permalink structure was a plain `/%postname%/`, because that is the same structure the post type `page` is using. Very complex additional rewrite rules were stored in the database to avoid collisions.

This is not a problem anymore. If your permalink structure is the same for posts and pages, posts are queried first (I hope I get this right :)).